# Getting error while displaying the image using imshow function

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, opencv, python

I want to convert RGB image to grayscale Image. I am getting an error when am trying to display the image.

code:

```
# convert image to gray scale

    import cv2
    
    img = cv2.imread("Images/lena.jpg")
    
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    cv2.imshow("output", imgGray)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\satya\PycharmProjects\opencv\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/satya/PycharmProjects/opencv/chapter_1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/satya/PycharmProjects/opencv/chapter_1.py", line 6, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("output", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Path and the file name I have specified correctly. I am not getting what the error is.

Comment: try absolute image path anyways. However I would suspect the cvtColor to crash, if no image was loaded... can you print the shape of img and of imgGray?

Comment: where do you have images folder with lena.jpg? Is it inside opencv directory?

Comment: Try wrapping the reading of the image from the path in a try catch statement. See if the error comes from reading the file.